# Difference between Socket Connection and XMPP Connection

Tags: sockets, blackberry, java-me, connection, xmpp

I am new to these two connections. I used to work with HTTP Connection before and now I wanna move to a new type of connection. I searched about connections and got these two types: Socket Connection and XMPP Connection. What is the main difference between them? I wanna use this for a chat application so which type is better recommended? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XMPP is a protocol for communication and so is HTTP. Both XMPP and HTTP will internally use socket connections.

You are confused between **application protocols** and **network layer**.

Comment: I see, I successfully integrated the HTTP connection. But no successful testing for XMPP connection. Check this POST I explained more my problem. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432407/try-to-connect-to-server-with-xmpp-connection

Answer (score 2):

Socket is the essential thing of any existing connections there is. If you want to use any connection that has a host point and a port, very likely (unless they write their own), they use `Socket` (to open a connection on a given port, send a message, and close the connection port) internally.