# Try to connect to server with XMPP Connection

Tags: blackberry, java-me, xmpp, smack

I am trying to connect from a blackberry device to an XMPP server. I searched over the web and found the smack.jar file that has the XMPP classes ready for use. So I created a new project and added the smack.jar file to the imported jar files. Then in the project I added the following:

```
public void login(String userName, String password) throws XMPPException {
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(IP, PORT, "gmail.com");
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    connection.connect();
    connection.login(userName, password);
}
```

The build is successful. Now when running the simulator and starting the project, i am getting the following error:

**Error starting test: Module 'smack-3.1.0' not found**

So I removed the smack.jar file from the imported jar files and added it manually to the classes of the project by adding a new file and selecting the smack.jar. When building the project I am getting this error:

**org.jivesoftware.smack.AccountManager: Error!: Missing stack map in: supportsAccountCreation at label: 9**

How to resolve this? How to connect to an XMPP server? Maybe smack isn't the right way!!

Please I need some help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like smack is from the [andtalk](http://code.google.com/p/andtalk/) project.  Quickly browsing the site, I don't see any claims of Java-ME support.  BlackBerry devices do not run full Java SE code, they can only run Java ME code, so most libraries won't work.   It looks like this is one of them that won't work.

Comment: But how to make smack work on blackberry? Is there any version of it for j2me phones including blackberry devices? If no what can I use similar to smack?

Comment: It looks like you've got some research ahead of you.

Comment: @Micheal No, Smack is from the [Smack project](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) ;-)  You are correct though in that there are no claims to JME support, although there are rumour that Blackberry QNX will at some point support the Dalvik JVM (same as Android) and Smack does run there (with some tweaks).

Answer (score 0):

Jxa is an XMPP client library that works in Blackberry: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxa/